# Why do I get a parsing exception for this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following patterns in a web service constructor:

```
rUsername = Pattern.compile("[A-z0-9]{4,30}");
rPassword = Pattern.compile("[A-z0-9!@#$%&*()=+-\\\\s]{6,30}");
rQuestion = Pattern.compile("[A-z0-9\\\\s?]{5,140}");
rAnswer = Pattern.compile("[A-z0-9\\\\s]{1,30}");
```

If I only have 2 slashes instead of the 4 there when I deploy my web application I get a parsing exception from Tomcat.

The username one works fine, but I seem to be having issues with the password, question and answer. The password will match "testasdas" but not "test1234", the question will not match anything with a space in it and the answer doesn't seem to match anything.

I want the password to be able to match lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, spaces and the symbols I threw in there. The question one should be able to match lowercase and uppercase, numbers, spaces and '?', and the answer just uppercase and lowercase letters, spaces and numbers.

EDIT: The patterns have changed to these:

```
rPassword = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&*()=+\\s-]{6,30}");
rQuestion = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9\\s?]{5,140}");
rAnswer = Pattern.compile("[A-z0-9\\s]{1,30}");
```

These are more or less how I want, but as pointed out in an answer I'm being quite restrictive on my password field which probably isn't a good idea. I don't hash anything before I save it because this is a college project nobody will ever use and I know that is a bad idea in the real world but it was not part of the requirements for the project. I do however have to stop SQL injection attacks, which is why everything is so restrictive. The idea was to mainly disallow the use of `'` which every SQL attack I know of needs to work, but I don't know how to disallow only that character alone.

Comment: I think the second part of your question (with the edited regexes) should be moved to a new question. Otherwise, the answers don't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your second regex:

```
[A-z0-9!@#$%&*()=+-\\\\s]
```

There are several errors here.

- `[A-z]` is incorrect, you need `[A-Za-z]` because there are some ASCII characters between `Z` and `a` that you probably don't want to match. But that's not the problem of your error.

More problematic is this section:

```
+-\\\\s
```

Translated from a Java string into an actual regex, this becomes

```
+-\\s
```

and that means (inside a character class) "Match any character between `+` and `\`, or any whitespace". `[+-\\]` is a valid range (ASCII 43-92), but it's not what you want.

But if you now remove the two extra backslashes, your character class becomes

```
+-\s
```

and that *is* a Syntax Error, because there is no ASCII range between `+` and "any whitespace".

**Solution:** Use

```
[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&*()=+\\s-]
```

or refrain from imposing limits on what characters your users may choose in a password in the first place.

Comment: +lots for "refrain from imposing limits on what characters your users may choose in a password in the first place".  If I want to include Greek/Chinese then why not - it shouldn't make any difference if you're hashing the password before saving it (you are hashing the password before saving it, right?)

Comment: Not at the moment, no. I understand that's what you must do in the real world but this is a college project that nobody will ever use so I'm not worried about security at all. It's pretty much just myself and my instructor that will ever use it. The main reason for the restriction was to simplify sanitizing the password for it to go in my SQL database, so all I really need to do is not allow `'`, correct? I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To match uppercase and lowercase letter you need to give pattern: - `[a-zA-Z]`

Try changing your pattern to: - 
`[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]{1,30}` for your answer..

For your question, that don't take whitespace, you can use `\\S` - non-whitespace character
`[a-zA-Z0-9\\S]{1,250}`
I think it should work.. You can make corresponding changes to remaining 2.

*EDIT: - You can also use `\\p{Z}` to match any Whitespace character..

See [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for a good tutorial on using Java Regular Expression..

Comment: In java `\s` is invalid because it is interpreted as an escape character, so you have to use `\\` to send through one `\` which is why I would normally use `\\s`. I did say in my OP that I got a parsing error from tomcat if I just used `\\s`, and `\\\\s` made that error go away. EDIT: got rid of the last `-` in my patterns and now `\\s` is working.

Comment: Yeah `\s` is a escape character that matches `Space`.. You only need to escape with an extra `backslash` to make it `\\s` if you literally want `\s` to be in your string..

Comment: it should actually be \\s. \s would give compiler error is not a valid carriage return